# Understanding entries in Latin dictionary

Tags: verbs, dictionary, wheelocks-latin

[image]

I started learning Latin yesterday by myself using the Wheelock's Latin textbook
My question was why are there 4 variations given of a word but only one translated meaning? What do these words mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We marked your question as duplicate because essentially the same question was asked before. But there's nothing wrong with that; nobody expects you to read all previous questions. The point is to have the questions linked so that other readers can find all the related content easily. I hope that the answers here and in the linked question are helpful, and I look forward to more questions we can help you with! (If you haven't already, consider going through our [quick introduction tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) which describes all the main features.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called the *principal parts* of the verb. They're the same verb, but in different forms.

Basically, one form isn't enough to know how to use a verb properly. Imagine if you didn't know English, and looked up the verb *give* in a dictionary. From that one form, how would you know the past tense? You'd probably guess **gived*, but that would be wrong. How are you supposed to know it's actually *gave*?

So English verbs have three principal parts: if you look up *give* in a dictionary for English-learners, it'll list these parts as *give, gave, given*. From these three forms, you can create all the other forms you might need: *he will give*, *I have given*, *you are giving*, and so on.

Latin has these same three principal parts: *dare* means "give", *dedī* means "gave", and *datum* means "given". But there's a slight oddity in Latin that means you need one extra form as well: *dō* specifically means "I give", because that one sometimes looks different from what you'd expect. So those are the four forms every dictionary will list.

(P.S. Sometimes verbs won't have all these forms; you'll see some verbs listed with only three, or some with only two. This generally means certain forms are *unattested*: they've never been seen "in the wild", and are assumed not to exist. For example, *meminī, meminisse*, "remember", only appears in the past tense. A good dictionary will also explain which forms are missing and how to work around that.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common way to present the words. See for instance [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amo#Latin).  They represent, respectively, the first person present active indicative (*amo*), the infinitive (*amare*), the perfect active (*amavi*) and the supine (*amatum*). In other words, they are **the same verb**, but in different conjugations.